# R in tcl/tk missing

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

While installing a package in R, I am getting error message in mu ubuntu 16.04 machine as shown belo dur t lack of tcl/tlk header. How to resolve it?

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/include/tcl8.6     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c tcltkimg.c -o tcltkimg.o
tcltkimg.c:2:16: fatal error: tk.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the tk-dev package to your system (e.g., with apt-get) as that contains the tk.h file; the command line invocation you need is (probably):

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
```

Comment: The GUI package management client can also be used. Either way is fine so long as the package is actually installed. (Debian and Ubuntu split up many software packages this way into runtime libraries and development code; header files are always development side.)